# Is it ok to create and handle the action items in the action bar withing fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, pane

### Background

I have a similar scenario as shown on the sample of android website about fragments (link [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html)) :

- small screen, portrait: single pane
- small screen, landscape: single pane
- 7" tablet, portrait: single pane
- 7" tablet, landscape: dual pane, wide
- 10" tablet, portrait: dual pane, narrow
- 10" tablet, landscape: dual pane, wide
- TV, landscape: dual pane, wide

The action bar in my case is always shown, and for now I only have action items in it.

### The problem

The next scenario is very weird:

- Device has one pane for portrait, and 2 panes for landscape.
- Both of my fragments create their own action bar items.
- Switching from portrait to landscape show all of the action items (which is what I want)
- Switching from landscape to portrait show all of the action items.

  This doesn't make much sense as the right pane doesn't exist, yet for some reason its fragment seems to exist in the fragmentManager, and its onCreateOptionsMenu is called even though it's not shown at all.

### What I've tried

I've tried to call invalidateOptionsMenu() on the activity that holds both fragments, but it didn't help

I've also added the next code for each of the fragments, and it works perfectly:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);
}
```

### The question

Why does it happen?

Is my solution of enabling/disabling the optionsMenu (thus enabling/disabling the action bar items creation by the fragments) a viable solution? Is there a better solution?

Is it even a good thing to make the fragments handle the action items in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally only have fragments handle action bar items in the single-pane case.  Logically the visible fragment owns all the screen space at that point, and since there's limited screen real estate it makes sense to use the action bar.  In the dual-pane case I tend to keep each fragment's UI within its own fragment and don't use the action bar.  However, if it makes visual sense in your scenario I don't see any reason why you can't.

My understanding is that the set of fragments in existence before a configuration change is recreated after a configuration change.  Android doesn't rely on the activity's layout file or anything like that.  Whatever fragments you have created is considered to be state to be preserved across configuration changes.  You might try manually removing the potentially unnecessary fragment when your activity is being torn down, and then count on Android to recreate it from the layout if it needs to exist after all.  However this is educated musing and not tested.

That said I don't see anything wrong with your current solution.

Comment: but how come the fragments still exist in the fragmentManager? is it possible it caches them in order to re-use them? the sample code shows that in order to check if it exists, it looks for it as a view instead of as a fragment. this is very weird.

Comment: The fragments are actually destroyed (unelss you call setRetainInstance) but the fragment manager saves its list of fragments as "state" that is restored when the activity is recreated.  Remember that, according to the Android docs, a fragment is not required to have any UI at all.  onCreateView is allowed to return null as long as you are creating the fragment manually using a FragmentTransaction instead of hosting it in your layout.  On the other hand if the fragment is in your layout and onCreateView returns null, the parent view will trigger a NullPointerException.

Comment: so, if and only if i put the fragment inside a layout file (xml), even if i have multiple layouts , one for each orientation, the fragment will stay forever? why would it want to re-create the menu when it's not even shown?

Comment: no, the fragment manager recreates all active fragments whether they're in the layout or not.  when the layout is inflated, onCreateView() will be called on the loaded fragment that matches the Id specified in the layout; if there is no such fragment (because your activity isn't restoring previous state) then the fragment you named in the layout is created.

Comment: Remember that a fragment isn't required to have UI.  When your activity is torn down, the fragment manager doesn't search the view hierarchy to see if a fragment has UI, doesn't record whether the fragment has UI or not, and when the activity is recreated does not conditionally recreate the fragment based on whether it's in the layout or not.  The fragment manager does not do any of these things.  Every fragment in the fragment manager is recreated when the activity is recreated.

Comment: So i'm back to the original question: why did it call onCreateOptionsMenu again? why was it created even though getActivity would return null in case i used it when i clicked on one of the action items?

Comment: What are you looking for, a rationale?  I don't think there's any good reason for this particular behavior.  I've explained how it works.  The fragment manager unconditionally recreates every fragment, period.  It doesn't have any smarts.  I doubt anyone on the Android team considered what might happen if a fragment added action bar items and then disappeared from the layout during a configuration change.  We just have to work with it as it is.

Comment: please don't be angry. that's what i was looking for , an explanation of what is going on (even without anything related to the actionbar) .

Answer (score 0):

You could, in the `onPrepareOptionsMenu(..)` method of the right-hand fragment, hide and show the menu items as appropriate, by looking at the `Configuration` obtainable from `getResources().getConfiguration()`.

As the other answer says, it is generally undesirable to change the amount of fragments shown during runtime - my app used to do this and I ran into thousands of issues.

Comment: If i rely on the configuration, it means the fragment assumes that it will always exist only under certain cases.

Comment: My approach only uses the Configuration to check whether to load the menu or not, rather than whether the Fragment exists or not.

Comment: but if the action items are related only to the fragment, you would want to show them only if the fragment is shown to the user (in case it's a ui fragment, of course).